# Lenovo TouchPad V15-IIL not working 10th gen intel

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I have a Lenovo V15-IIL 82C500GCGE notebook, with an Intel Gen10 i5-1035G1 CPU and an Intel chipset. The system is Ubuntu is 20.04 with all updates.
The touchpad is not working.

Is it possible to get a driver for the Intel Serial IO from/for the 10 Generation Intel Chipset?

If it helps you, in Windows 10 is the same problem, after installing a clean Windows 10 it is needed to install this driver to get it working: [Intel Serial-IO (SIO) Driver for Windows 10 (64-bit) - V14-IIL, V15-IIL](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/de/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v15-iil/82c5/82c500gcge/pf1ckxnc/downloads/driver-list/component?name=Chipset)

Comment: You can check this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Serial_input_device_to_kernel_input

Comment: thanks sorry this way can not work. It is needed to find a driver for the intel io system. it must be a newer version of the i2c sub system.

Comment: @TUXBerlin Have you solved this problem by now?

Answer (score 5):

Run `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` and append `i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs`

To `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line to be:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"
```

Save the file and run in a terminal

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot and the touchpad should work.

Source https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1881322

Comment: So no drivers are needed.

Comment: superb finding, really easy and helpful

Comment: Out of the numerous fixes for this issue I've encountered from various sources, I can confirm that this one ACTUALLY WORKS on my Lenovo IdeaPad 3 15IIL05 running Ubunut 20.04 LTS. And it is a simple fix to boot. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It did not solve my problem (Lenovo Legion 5 15ITH6). I had to downgrade the kernel to 5.13 and disable secure boot in BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I have Ideapad 3 15IIL05 with i3, Ubuntu 22.04, kernel 5.15. Touchpad was not recognised at all!

What worked for me was:

1. I downgraded my kernel to 5.13.0, followed link below.

https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-change-default-kernel-in-ubuntu-22-04-20-04-lts/

2. ONLY THEN solution on updating grub worked!!!

Open terminal and run following command:

> sudo nano /etc/default/grub

then add **i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs** to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** line to be:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs"

**CTRL + X > Y > Enter** to save and exit in **nano**, then in the terminal run:

> sudo update-grub

Reboot

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1227171)

Comment: I know, I'm sorry, I'm new to all this and so frustrated, as still no fix for touch-pad (((

downgrading kernel and all sorts.. just wont work

Comment: This is a copy of an existing question.