# Lenovo V15-IIL touchpad not detected in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, 22.04

I have recently updated my lenovo 15-IIL to the latest ubuntu 22.04 LTS from ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS. Assuming that since its LTS release there shouldn't be major bugs I updated my system.

The problem is I can't use my touchpad. It's not recognized at all by the system. However, the usb mouse works completely fine.

I am aware that this model had this exact problem earlier and it could be solved by appending kernel parameters as in the thread here: [Lenovo TouchPad V15-IIL not working 10th gen intel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280240/lenovo-touchpad-v15-iil-not-working-10th-gen-intel)

The above method does not work when it comes to ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Can anybody help and confirm if there is any solution for ubuntu 22.04 ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's works if you downgrade to the kernel 5.13 and follow this steps [Lenovo TouchPad V15-IIL not working 10th gen intel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280240/lenovo-touchpad-v15-iil-not-working-10th-gen-intel)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem with kernel 5.15.0-56 on my Lenovo ThinkPad E14 Gen 2 laptop. I took the kernel downgrade workaround to version 5.15.0-52 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on a brand new Lenovo T14s with a clean ubuntu 22.04 install. The problem also occurred on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Therefore, I went to the BIOS and saw that the touchpad was disabled. Enabling it did the job. Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see any option of configuring touchpad in BIOS. Can you share your screenshot of BIOS if possible? My model is V series 15-IIL

Comment: I went to the [Lenovo BIOS Simulator center](https://download.lenovo.com/bsco/index.html) to compare our BIOS's and saw that your BIOS unfortunately does not have the aforementioned option.